# How to specify the interacting or owner or deployer address in ethersjs?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

How can I specify a particular address interacting from or deploying a contract in ethersjs? Basically, how can I specify who is the signer or owner or user address in ethersjs?

In the tests, it seems like the first account from the list of dummy signers will always be picked as the address doing all the stuff.

In Truffle, there is something along this:

```
deployer.deploy(myContract, { from: "0x123" });
```

I'm using hardhat and ethersjs. How can I do something similar by specifying an address interacting or deploying a contract in ethersjs too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Contract and ContractFactory objects have a method called `connect` that you can use to do this.
See docs for [Contract](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-connect) and [ContractFactory](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory-connect).

Assuming you have an instance of the Signer object called `signer`, you can do something like this:

```
// Connect signer to contract and call the eat method on contract
contract.connect(signer).eat('Pizza');
```